# creating nested functions in python by iterating through multiple data frames in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to create 2 functions to create 2 columns in `details` `data frame`.The `data frames` are given below.

```
data_set=pd.DataFrame({'id':['A_1','B_1','C_1'],'maths':[100,5,30],'chemistry': [90,40,20],'physics':[80,50,10],'language':[80,90,65]})
control=pd.DataFrame({'feature1':['maths','chemistry','physics','french','biology'],'feature2': ['first','first','two','three','two']})
details=pd.DataFrame({'feature1':['maths','chemistry','physics']})
```

To create a new column in `details` called `lower`,the `func1 algorithm` goes like this and to create another column `upper` modify the following algorithm  for `func2` replacing minus `-30 with +30` and and `if x>100: return 0 else return x`

```
`details['lower']=apply(details, func1(x),axis=1)`
```

Inside the `func1(x)`

```
`if control.feature1==x.feature1 and control.feature2==first`
   `return x =data_set[x['feature1'].unique()]` 
`else x=data_set[x['feature1'].unique()]-30`
     `if x<0 return 0 
      else return x`
```

Similar function for `upper` column
`details['upper']=details.apply(details,func2(x),axis=1)`
Finally I will create a new function
`upper_lower(details,control, data_set)`
which will include these 2 functions.
I tried to convert these algorithms to code. but got many errors.To start with I tried this to get the results of lower part.
I used the following code snippet and got some hints.

```
    data_first=data_set[details['feature1'].unique()]
    d=data_first-30
    d_ = d.mask(d < 0, 0)
    d_
    The final data frame is
   maths    chemistry   physics
    80       70          60
     0      20           30
    10       0           0
```

After that I became clueless.This is a simple example but the data_set is bigger.
What I expect is `details['lower'] =[80,70,60]` for the first ID.

```
feature1  lower 
maths      80
chemistry  70
physics    60
```

Since I am a beginner in python and pandas, need help.

Comment: is ``d_`` the expected output?

Comment: `@sammywemmy`After seeing your comment I modified the question a bit.`details[lower] =[80,70,60]` for the first ID`